# Can Python edit individual list items?

Tags: list, python-2.7

I wrote a program that selects random words from lists to make a sentence. I want to write grammar rules for this. Right now I am working on plurals.

I want to add an s or es to the end of the selected word in 'nouns' if the word "those" is selected from list5.

```
import random   
class Wrds(object):

    verbs = [
        "walk", "run"           
    ]

    pronouns = [
        "I", "you"
    ]

    help_verbs = [
        "will", "might"
    ]

    nouns = [
    "boy", "girl"
    ]

    list5 = [
    "the", "that", "this", "a", "those"
    ]

    punctuation = [
       ".", "?", "!"
    ]

    def result(self):
        a = random.choice(Wrds.verbs)
        b = random.choice(Wrds.pronouns)
        c = random.choice(Wrds.help_verbs)
        d = random.choice(Wrds.nouns)
        e = random.choice(Wrds.list5)
        f = random.choice(Wrds.punctuation)     
        print "%s %s %s %s %s%s" % (b, c, a, e, d, f)

def ask():

    a = raw_input("> ")
    if a == "go":   
        w = Wrds()
        return w.result()

    elif a == "exit":
        exit()

while True:         
    ask()
```

Comment: This is a little more complicated than "editing". Your data structures need major reworking.

Comment: And more descriptive names, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `print` statement in the `result` method, add:

```
    if e == 'those':
        d += 's'
```

Comment: `if e in ('those', 'these'):`

Comment: Which requires changing the code. Always a bad thing.

Comment: Simple is good, but also doesn't give much leeway for adding `-es` either. Would probably need a list of words where the 'e' should be added and then something like `if d in add_e_dict: ending = 'es'`